# Reporting through PMD in Maven

Tags: android, maven

I am running a Maven command in my project's directory as "mvn pmd:pmd", it will generates xml files of reports of errors in the code but I can't find the exact source of that particular error in the code from that Report because it have only declared errors but not give any line number or class name where that particular error was occured. That's why we unable to find exact wrong code in my project. Please help me out from this problem; how we get information of line number and class name in the pdm report with Maven.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice if you could give the error message you get during the mvn pdm:pdm call ? (isn't that mvn pmd:pmd ?)

Comment: Sorry khmarbaise, it is mvn pmd:pmd

Comment: It is running successfully but it generates reports in target folder and that report doesn't give any details about line number and source class.

Comment: In my build there is a pmd.xml file generated in the target folder which contains line/column numbers of the problems...The question is: Do you like to have a HTML report about that? If yes you need to run mvn site after that.

Comment: Thanx It works but it only shows warnings in unused imports, variables and try, catch blocks but I want more as static code analysis from which wrong logics can be determined.

Comment: Than you have to look for other metrics which will give such kind of information, but the things you mentioned are potential problems (http://pmd.sourceforge.net/). The question is what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do the report into HTML

> mvn pmd:pmd site

but based on the docs of pmd-plugin it should generate an HTML report already.